# Can I override a hard-code value of deployment.yaml during install helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-deployment

Helm: Can I override a hard-code value of deployment.yaml during install the helm chart?

Currently, I have got an exist helm chart that created by another team. But they hard coded the value of image's name:version in the deployment.yaml file in their project.

I use helm-operator in my cluster, and all the helm charts deployed via HelmRelease yaml.

So what can I do to replace this value?

Unfortunately, they can't fix it in the near future and I can't edit their files.

Comment: Your deployment creates replicasets, just do "kubectl edit replicaset nameofyourreplicaset" and it should restart the pods with the correct image that you set during edit, or if it does not do that you can delete them and when they restart they will use the new image.